# Tool to generate a slim Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-8, disk-image

Since I'm running a laptop with a 20 GB SSD, i cannot easily fit Windows 8.1 plus personal files on the SSD, let alone install more software.

How can i generate a slimmed-down Windows 8.1? What software would I be able to use to generate a new, slimmer install disk I can use on my small SSD?

I've considered the following tools:

- [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/)
- [WinReducer](http://www.winreducer.net/)

These are the factors I'm looking at.

- Limitations of free version
- Ease of use for non-experts
- Achievable Smallness
- Differences in result
- Reliability/stability of result
- Amount of diskspace and RAM required to run the tool
- Good/bad experiences of users

Also open to alternative methods, including a manual approach with DISM.

Comment: Can I ask why you are focused on Win 8.1 - It seems that 10 is slimmer by design but better yet there are a number of very good, slim, Linux distributions such as DSL, Lubuntu, etc.

Comment: Wow, what a requirement. I'd not even consider installing it on a disk below 100 GB for the applications I want to run and you want to get down to 20 GB. May I ask what you want to use it for?

Comment: @SteveBarnes, because i own 8.1, not 10. Not trying to run Linux, Thx

Comment: @Thomas, for computing. This HP laptop was sold to me by Best Buy containing a 20 GB SSD drive with Win 8 preinstalled-- not really unusual. Check out the 2 tools i listed, and also http://www.nliteos.com/. Minimizing a Windows install is not a new thing. Thx

Answer (score 1):

While Windows 8 is not currently listed as available yet, (promised for later this year), you should keep an eye on [WinBuilder](http://winbuilder.net/) which allows various OS images to be created via the Windows PE mechanism. There is also a lot of discussion on [Reboot](http://reboot.pro/forum/22/)

- Free - Gratis
- Simple to use

Comment: thx for this! But for now, just looking at tools which already support 8.1.